# Is there a better way to connect system audio to mic output?

Tags: windows, audio, android, skype, microphone

Is there a better way to connect system audio to mic output? I would like to connect text-to-speech software to my audio output so that the person who I am calling only hears the robot voice in real time and not my microphone.

Please keep in mind that I have already tried Stereo Mix on my laptop. It doesn't quite work. The resulting audio sounds very distorted and muffled. Also, it occasionally (and unpredictably) goes silent. I've tried this solution across multiple laptops and the result is the same. It isn't the TTS software, either. Even YouTube videos sound muted and crackly.

With this in mind, what's a better solution for this problem, one that preserves audio quality?

A solution for both Windows 11 PCs and Android phones would be very appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.